# Ionic Cordova Project Returns Error on Build and Update ios

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-ios

I am running an ionic v1 project and i have just recently updated my cordova-ios to 4.5.0. My cordova, node and ionic versions are as follows

cordova version 6.4.0
node version 6.9.0
ionic version 1.7.15
cordova-ios 4.5.0

Each time i run this `ionic build ios`, i get an error

```
Error: cordovaProject.projectConfig.getFileResources is not a function
```

And each time i run this `ionic platform update ios` i get this error

```
mv: no such file or directory: /{PROJECT_PATH}/platforms/ios/Loanstreet Partners.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/xcschemes/__PROJECT_NAME__.xcscheme
```

Kinda confused on what step to take to rectify this. 
Any help appreciated.